# Horizontal polarization and vertical polarization

Tags: polarization

let say i have link between two points.
one has omni antenna (horizontal polarization)
and the second has directional antenna   (Horizontal polarization and vertical polarization with only one cable RF input)

my question -

if i rotate the second antenna in 90 degree
will the link break?
thank you very much.